# Spring security Oauth 2 is using GET request instead of POST

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, http-post, interceptor

I am using Oauth2 with spring security to accept only POST authentication request but it ignores interceptor method=POST parameter and always uses GET request to authenticate  calls instead
, below is my spring-security.xml

Can anyone suggest me what that iam missing to make all request as POST only
Thanks

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2" 
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />
</bean>

    <!-- Just for testing... -->
<http pattern="/oauth/cache_approvals" security="none" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" />
<http pattern="/oauth/uncache_approvals" security="none" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" />

<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" method="POST" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block so we can deal with authorization and error handling 
    separately. This isn't mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
<http pattern="/Login/*" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/Login/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Login" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Login/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>                   
                    <password-encoder hash="sha" />
                    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


<bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<!-- Used for the persistenceof tokens (currently an in memory implementation) 
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />-->

    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
<!-- Used to create token and and every thing about them except for their persistence that is reposibility of TokenStore (Given here is a default implementation) -->
<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<!-- authorization-server aka AuthorizationServerTokenServices is an interface that defines everything necessary for token management -->
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="Login" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />
<!-- ClientsDeailsService: Entry Point to clients database (given is in memory implementation) -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
<!-- client -->
<oauth:client client-id="the_client" authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_USER" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

<oauth:client client-id="DefaultDevcoClient" authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="BANGBANGBANG" authorities="ROLE_USER" />

</oauth:client-details-service>


<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Comment: i'm having same issue, have you found the workaround for this problem?

Comment: spring-security-oauth2-1.0.RELEASE will use get method and spring-security-oauth2-2.0.4.RELEASE uses POST method for authentication

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to create custom filters instead and my detailed blog post is here 
[spring security configuration](http://clofus.com/myblog/?p=61)